# How to run a specific version of Qt with Notepadqq

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, qt, vmware-workstation, notepadqq

I have two versions of Ubuntu running on different VMs under VMWare workstation: 16.04 and 18.04.

I really dislike the file open/save interface I have on 18.05 and I like the one I have on 16.04. I assume the issue is the different versions of Qt running.

On 16.04 I seem to be running
Notepadqq v.1.4.2 and Qt 5.5.1

On 18.04 I seem to be running
Notepadqq v.1.4.2 and Qt 5.9.5

That is, the same version of Notepadqq but different versions of Qt.

When I do a

```
whereis qt
```

in both VMs, I get "nothing" back.  All I see is

```
qt:
```

Is my assumption correct? Is the cause of the different file open/save GUI due to a difference in qt versions or is it a difference in OS (16.04 v 18.04) versions?

If it is a difference in Qt versions, how do I go from Qt version 5.9.5 back to 5.5.1 in my 18.04 VM?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? Have you amended the style used by Qt?

Comment: gsxruk, thank you for answering.  I do not understand your question.

Comment: (Sorry for the repeat. I took more than 5 minutes to edit this answer.)

gsxruk, thank you for answering.  I do not understand your question.

I think my answers to your questions are:
1) Gnome. How does one determine what the desktop environment is for sure?
2) How does one amend the style used by Qt? Are you referring to https://www.pcsuggest.com/qt5ct-change-qt5-application-style/ ?

Comment: If you go to "Settings" and then "About" you will see Gnome somewhere in there if you are using Gnome. Have you changed anything using qt5ct? The reason I ask, is that when I lauch Notepadqq in 16.04 and 18.04, I see no difference in the open/save dialog.

Comment: Sigh.  There is nothing in "About" about Gnome in settings.

You can see what my desktop looks like here: https://pasteboard.co/HwyQRbr.png

Also, I have not installed or used qt5ct.

Comment: And another printscreen:  https://pasteboard.co/HwyTYcg.png

Comment: Your 2nd screenshot shows "Gnome 3.28.2".

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of the open/save dialog in 16.04 and 18.04?

Comment: The 18.04 version is here: https://pasteboard.co/HwAIOPi.png.  The 16.04 version is here: https://pasteboard.co/HwANesp.png . What I'd prefer would be a combination of both where I have a list of folders  PLUS the ability to paste in a full pathname. But in the absence of that, I MUCH prefer the ability to paste in a name.

Comment: In 18.04 you have a native dialog. In 16.04 you have don't have a native dialog. It's a little strange because I have a non-native dialog in both 16.04 and 18.04 (which is what you want). How did you install Notepadqq? Did you install it using the ppa?

Comment: @gsxruk thank you so much for helping me.  (1) sudo add-apt-repository ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq (2) sudo apt-get update (3) sudo apt-get install notepadqq  (4) I followed the instructions in https://tecadmin.net/install-notepadqq-text-editor-ubuntu/

Comment: As far as I can tell, I did the same installation process in 16.04 as I did in 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A second option.

The only way I can think of to ensure this works as you require is to modify the source code and build notepadqq yourself. This is because, Qt decides if a native dialog is used unless the developer overrides this behaviour (which isn't the case here).

These steps will guide you through this process.

**Remove the notepadqq snap**

```
sudo snap remove notepadqq
```

**Install prerequisites**

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
sudo apt install qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools qtwebengine5-dev libqt5websockets5-dev libqt5svg5 libqt5svg5-dev
```

**Download the notepadqq source**

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone --recursive https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq.git
```

**Create the patch file**

I've written a patch file to make it easier to make the required modifications. This patch file will force the use of a non-native dialog.

Open a new file in a text editor, copy the following and then paste it into the text editor. Save the document as `notepadqq.patch` in `~/Downloads`. Make sure you copy the entire file exactly.

```
--- mainwindow.cpp  2018-07-29 13:42:51.758184000 +0100
+++ mainwindow_patched.cpp  2018-07-29 13:53:06.888952000 +0100
@@ -845,7 +845,7 @@
                                 tr("Open"),
                                 defaultUrl,
                                 tr("All files (*)"),
-                                0, 0);
+                                0, QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

     if (fileNames.empty())
         return;
@@ -866,7 +866,7 @@
     BackupServicePauser bsp; bsp.pause();

     // Select directory
-    QString folder = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Folder"), defaultUrl.toLocalFile(), 0);
+    QString folder = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Folder"), defaultUrl.toLocalFile(), QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
     if (folder.isEmpty())
         return;

@@ -1052,7 +1052,7 @@
                            tr("Save as"),
                            getSaveDialogDefaultFileName(tabWidget, tab).toLocalFile(),
                            tr("Any file (*)"),
-                           nullptr, nullptr);
+                           nullptr, QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

     if (filename != "") {
         m_settings.General.setLastSelectedDir(QFileInfo(filename).absolutePath());
@@ -2463,7 +2463,7 @@
     // See https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq/issues/654
     BackupServicePauser bsp; bsp.pause();

-    QString file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Extension"), QString(), "Notepadqq extensions (*.nqqext)");
+    QString file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Extension"), QString(), "Notepadqq extensions (*.nqqext)", nullptr, QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
     if (!file.isNull()) {
         Extensions::InstallExtension *installExt = new Extensions::InstallExtension(file, this);
         installExt->exec();
@@ -2547,7 +2547,7 @@
                            tr("Open Session..."),
                            recentFolder,
                            tr("Session file (*.xml);;Any file (*)"),
-                           0, 0);
+                           0, QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

     if (filePath.isEmpty())
         return;
@@ -2574,6 +2574,7 @@
     dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
     dialog.setDefaultSuffix("xml");
     dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);
+    dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

     if (!dialog.exec())
         return;
```

**Apply the patch file**

```
cd ~/Downloads
patch ~/Downloads/notepadqq/src/ui/mainwindow.cpp notepadqq.patch
```

**Build and install notepadqq**

```
cd ~/Downloads/notepadqq
./configure --prefix /usr
make
sudo make install
```

**To make command nqq work (optional)**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/notepadqq /usr/bin/nqq
```

Launch notepadqq. Now, you should have what you had before but the open/save dialog should be non-native.

I did notice that the icon for notepadqq does not appear. If I find out how to fix that, I'll update the answer.

Hope that helps.

**Update for icon**

It looks like the icon cache has to be updated as follows.

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor/
```

The icon is displayed correctly once this command has been executed.

Comment: Utterly, absolutely amazing! @gsxruk! It works!!!  Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: No problem and pleased it worked for you. And if that's the case, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer ... but I have fewer than 15 reputation points.

Comment: While I have your attention, @gsxruk, I am just now reading https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications .  Do you recommend I use gksu/gksudo rather than sudo to launch nqq when I need root privileges?

Comment: I've always been a little unsure on that too and I thought it was deprecated/obsolete these days. I don't really use it, I always use vi when I'm amending root files. [This article](https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/) may be of interest and it looks up to date.

Comment: One other point on notepadqq. It would be worth asking the developer to add an option to disable native dialogs as a feature enhancement. Otherwise, you'll have to do this every time you install Ubuntu fresh. He doesn't have to, but it can't hurt to ask!

Comment: In terms of sudo nqq --allow-root ... I _think_ it is safe.  notepadqq seems to even keep different saved state depending on whether --allow-root is used or not.

Comment: In terms of a feature request, I did as you suggested, @gsxruk.  See https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq/issues/737 .  And, again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why, but it looks like the application GUI behaves differently when installed using the PPA compared to when it is installed as a snap. I have seen this with another application.

If you carry out the following steps, you should end up with notepadqq using a non-native open/save dialog in Ubuntu 18.04.

**Uninstall the current notepadqq**

```
sudo apt remove notepadqq
```

**Clean up the system by removing the PPA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq
sudo apt update
```

**Install notepadqq as a snap**

```
sudo snap install notepadqq
```

Launch notepadqq and check the open/save dialog. On my system, the non-native dialog appears.

Comment: I think you'll find those error messages were present anyway. They were on mine in both cases. But that may be a question you need to raise with the developer.

Comment: (I'm sorry I deleted my comment after you answered.  Here's my comment again.) Wow, that worked!  The only two changes - and they are minor annoyances - are (1)  that I can only launch with "notepadqq" rather than "nqq".  (2) I'm getting error messages when I launch notepadqq. See https://pasteboard.co/HwH98Tw.png for the error messages.

Comment: (a) @gsxruk, Thank you so much!!!  (b) Do you know how to contact the developer?

Comment: A good place to start would be the project website [here](https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq). You should be able to raise an issue.

Comment: Ok, another problem.  "sudo notepadqq --allow-root" no longer works.  Sigh.